# Why can't I find the TIN Management tool in 3D Analyst toolbox?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arctoolbox, 3d-analyst, tin

I am looking for the CREATE TIN tool in the 3D Analyst toolbox, but I can´t find it. Any ideas why I can't find it?

Answer (score 4):

First you need to enable the extension (if you have the license for this):

[image]

Create TIN (3D Analyst)
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q90000001v000000

You can search for this:

[image]

Comment: Should you not have the extension you can right click on the top of the tool box and unselect 'Hide Locked Tools', this will enable you to locate these tools and insert them into models without having a license, but you will not be able to run the model without it; you can also access the help file without the license. At some stage though you're going to need that license to get it to work. This approach also works when creating a model using Advanced (INFO) tools but only having a Basic (View) license. NOTE: you can put them in and link but cannot open to change parameters.

Answer (score 1):

3D Analyst tools >> Data management >> TIN >> create TIN